# How to implement SHA1 in C

Tags: c, sha1, hmacsha1

I am trying to wrap my head around HOTP values, and I believe the essential building block is understanding the SHA-1 hashing function. I am coding in C, and I have seen many examples of people implementing the SHA1 function using libraries, such as OpenSSL. My question is, if I am attempting to implement my code on hardware that will not have internet access, is it viable to implement SHA1 using a library, or is it possible to create the function from scratch in the code?

I have tried implementing the sha1 algorithm by using libraries from openSSL, however I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: What internet access has to do with that? SHA1 is a deterministic algorithm which depends on the input data only. And is perfectly implementable both from scratch or using specific libraries.

Comment: Either one. It's just a big long algorithm written down in RFC 3174. You can either write it in C yourself, or use someone else's one, like OpenSSL's. You don't have to have the Internet to use the non-Internet parts of OpenSSL.

Comment: It's pretty unclear if you're asking how to implement SHA-1 or if you're asking how to use a library that already has a SHA-1 implemenation. If it's the former, have you read https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3174.txt?

Comment: My question about the internet was because I didn't fully understand the functionality of the library, but I understand now. I think it will be much easier to use OpenSSL's library and the call the sha function from there.

Comment: @Cubic I wanted to know if it would be a better approach to implement SHA-1 or use a library that already has the implementation if I am trying to use SHA-1 in a piece of hardware.

Comment: @ChrisDeSantiago If it is for some security sensitive application - the first rule is "do not implement your own security algorithms, but use the proven existing ones".

Comment: @Eugene sh. I understand. I will take the approach of implementing a preexisting SHA-1 algorithm using a library.

Comment: I was told once in college "If you're writing security sensitive software, stop, because you're doing it wrong." Heh, obviously that doesn't apply to _everybody_ (_somebody_ has to write it). But yeah, if this to meet an actual security requirement, far better to use the existing software that's got billions of hours of deployment usage, thousands of eyes on it, etc. But if this is for your own edification, knock yourself out. I did SHA-256 on an arduino once. Wikipedia even [spells out the algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) for you.